# How to use Gluon folders of iOS, android, desktop (And main) that make up a Gluon project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, javafx, gluon

I am trying to set up my Gluon project by putting platform/os specific code in their respective folder (The automatically created project set up in a newly created Gluon project). However no matter what task I do with Gradle it end up taking what is the `Main` folder.

Lets say I want to have a `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View` with a `javafx.scene.control.Button`in it - and have it labeled differently by stating from which folder it came from (main, android, desktop or iOS). How would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't require specific platform code in your project.

If what you want is custom styling based on the platform, you can use `Platform.getCurrent().name()` and then react based on it.

For instance, the `MyDevoxx` [app](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/java/com/devoxx/DevoxxApplication.java#L149) loads different css files based on platform and type of device.

A good way to understand how the platform specific folders work is by having a look at the Charm Down [library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down), and the implementation for the different services.

As you'll notice those folders contain both java and specific platform code.

A sample on how you can create a new service can be found [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native). For instance, the `AndroidLogService` implementation makes use of `android.util.Log`, while the `IOSLogService` makes use of native Objective-C (see `Log.m`). This native code has to be compiled as a native library (see `installNativeLib` task in the build file).

In any case, the service is called from the `main` package:

```
Services.get(LogService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.log(message));
```

When you deploy your application to a specific platform, only the implementation for that platform is called.

So if you need a new service you can create it following the design of those in Charm Down.

Comment: I cannot right click on my gluon project in Eclipse (package explorer) to open Gluon Mobile Settings. I can download Charm Down library but I do not know how to make them importable for my java classes in Eclipse. They seem to be depening on eachother - as well as a predetermined package structure, so it seems very difficult to manually move classes of the services that i am interested of into my project . I assume you need to edit the `build.gradle` to include them but I do not know how. How can I use these Services?

Comment: Importing them in Netbeans was easy. I will take a closer look at the services. When I posted this question I was more looking at how to adapt the GUI depending on desktop/mobile - so I thought I could use these folders to prevent the mobile users of the app to also have all the GUI of dekstop - and prevent desktop users from having all mobile GUI - that they respectively do not use. If I use if statements that would mean users will carry a lot of dead code in the app.

Comment: I can't follow the GoNative example. The project structure has changed, when doing the task intallNativeLibrary - it should look into `GoNativeApp` and not `GoNative`[root]?

Comment: The latest Gluon plugin version generates a root project and a subproject with the Gluon Mobile project. But `GoNative` from GitHub keeps the old single project structure.

Comment: I built `libLog.a` in a standard `Gradle` project - and "installed" it. That helped me understand the project structure of Gluon better. And I could manually move it all into the right folders of Gluon